# Passing text after onclick on href in jQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the text from onclick href in particular href when class="bank cur" while getting the data-name="建设银行"

But it does not work. In function i am getting nothing to pass.Please help how to get value the text.

```
    <ul class="bank_list">
     <li class="bank_1" data-name="建设银行"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank cur"></a></li>
 <li class="bank_2" data-name="CHINA BANK"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank "></a></li>
 <li class="bank_3" data-name="OCBC BANK"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bank "></a></li>
```

and pass it to change the 选择银行 to 建设银行 :

```
<em name="bankName" id="bankNameList">选择银行</em>
```

jQUERY :

```
$(".bank").click(function(){
            $(".bank").removeClass('cur')     
            $(this).addClass('cur')
    })


    $(".add_bankcard").click(function () {
        $(".binding_bankcard_input").css("display","block")

    }); 

    $("#bankNameList").click(function () {
        $(".tikuan_bank").css("display","block")

    });
```

Comment: $(this).attr('href');

Comment: @NewbeeDev this code not working

Comment: Where do you try to read it? https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding click events to the anchor, but all of the data attributes you want to read are on the li. So you need to use data() on the parent element.

```
$(".bank").click(function(){             
    $(".bank").removeClass('cur');    
    $(this).addClass('cur');
    var name = $(this).parent("li").data("name");
    console.log(name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the content of the clicked element like so:

```
$(".bank").click(function(event){
   var $target = $(event.target);
   $target.text(); // gets text (of a link, div, etc)
   $target.val();  // gets value (of an input)
   $target.html(); // gets html 
   $target.attr('href'); //gets value of anchor href attrib
   $target.data('name'); //gets value of data field
   // etc
});
```

If you inspect the `event` object you may discover some more meaningful attributes.

For your specific case you could try:

```
$('.bank.cur').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $target = $(event.target);
  var $li     = $target.parent();
  var bank    = $li.data('name');
  // now do something with the value of 'var bank'
});
```

Comment: Hi , how do i set if the condition of class="bank cur" only will pick up the text. It's seems your code cant explain very well

Comment: do you mean, how do you select the element with those classes?  Use `$('.bank.cur')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the data attribute from the event target and set it as the text of the #bankNameList element. Here's how you would do this in your current code:

```
$(".bank").click(function(){
  // get the data attribute's value
  var name = $(this).data("name")

  // set the text of #bankNameList to the value
  $("#bankNameList").text(name)

  $(".bank").removeClass('cur')
  $(this).addClass('cur')
})
```

Comment: Hi austin , im getting undefined value